# How do I add a time delay to a signal in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, signal-processing

This is my first question here on stackoverflow, bear with me please. I get a dictionary-like list with time and values for each timestamp and based on those values I need to create a lower bound and higher bound with time-delay. I got the lower bound to work but I'm struggling with the higher bound.

The signal that I want to generate looks like this(shorter version):

```
timeList=              [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
myGeneratedHigherBound=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
signalDataList=        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
myGeneratedLowerBound= [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

```
####### creating the lower bound ######
def CalcExpResultL(commandSignal):
    #the dataList that I am generating
    dataListL = []
    #time stamps
    timeListL=commandSignal[0]
    for i in range(len(commandSignal[0])):
        if (commandSignal[1][i] == 0 or (commandSignal[1][i] == 1 and commandSignal[1][i-25] == 0)):
            dataListL.append(500)
        elif (commandSignal[1][i] == 1 and not commandSignal[1][i+25] == 0):
            dataListL.append(2025)
        else:
            dataListL.append(500)

    return [timeListL,dataListL]
```

```
####### creating higher bound ######
def CalcExpResultH(commandSignal):
    dataListH = []
    timeListH=commandSignal[0]
    length = len(commandSignal[0])-25
    
    for i in range(length):
        if (commandSignal[1][i] == 0 and not commandSignal[1][i+25] == 0):
            dataListH.append(540)
        elif(commandSignal[1][i] == 1 or (commandSignal[1][i] == 0 and commandSignal[1][i-25] ==1)):
            dataListH.append(2045)
        else:
            dataListH.append(540)
            
    #my solution to an error "index out of bounds"
    remainder = len(timeListH) - len(dataListH)
    for i in range(remainder):
        dataListH.append(540)

    return [timeListH,dataListH]
```

I have tried multiple combinations of conditions, but none of them worked, i either got the first higher bound delay right and the second didn't even appear, or vice-versa.

What I have achieved so far:
[image]

Comment: Are the intervals and time delays fixed values? Meaning, do you want to calculate the lower and upper bounds for a fixed amount of entries in your given signal list?

Comment: I have trouble understanding what is your case about. I am confused with the meaning of "lower/higher bound with time delay"

Comment: Yes, I want to calculate for a fixed amount of entries. 
And the lower and higher bounderies around the main signal(blue in the image), and the delay means that my boundaries change its value sooner or later(depending on the boundary) than the main signal.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the delay, so I will outline a general solution.  For reporting `m` time points from `n` events, it will be `O(m + n log(n))`.

First we need the idea of *events*.  An event has:

```
start
end
value
```

We will start with a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) of events for observed values.  Those look like `Event(start, start+duration, value)`.

We will turn that into another list of when specific values are bounds. (The logic for upper bounds is very similar.) In pseudocode we:

```
min_events = []
for event in observations sorted by end:
    # Remove/modify trailing min_events that this is a better value than.
    while 0 < len(min_events) and
            event.start < min_events[-1].end and
            event.value < min_events[-1].value:
        tail_event = min_events.pop()
        if tail_event.start < event.start:
            min_events.append(
                Event(tail_event.start, event.end, tail_event.value)
            )

    # Add this value into min_events.
    if 0 == len(min_events) or event.value <= min_events[-1].value:
        min_events.append(event)
    elif min_events[-1].end < event.end:
        min_events.append(
            Event(min_events[-1].end, event.end, event.value)
        )
```

And now we merely need to:

```
i = 0
for time in times to report on:
    while i < len(min_events) and min_events[i].end <= time:
        i += 1
    if i < len(min_events) and min_events[i].start <= time:
        answer.append(min_events[i].value)
    else:
        answer.append(None)
```

Now to do a complexity analysis.  We have to sort `n` events for time `O(n log(n))`.  For each observed event we check for cleanup (which we'll attribute to the inserting events), insert at most 2 events, and later have to either delete or iterate past the two.  Making for an additional `O(n)` work. And then reporting each time point is `O(1)` for `O(m)` for all time points.  This makes the complexity `O(m + n log(n))`.